# Do the post level 50 specalizations provide anything apart from armor?

Tags: halo-4

After you reach SR 50 in Halo 4 you get to choose a specalization such as Wetwork, Operator, Stalker, etc and these levels go through from 1 - 10. Once you have your chosen unlock, do they grant you any special abilities or is it just armor? I have the full set of Venator armour with a fairly distinctive visor and would like to keep it unless there are other benefits.

It's quite overwhelming the amount of customization and unlocks in Halo: 4.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Yes the specializations unlock unique bonus armor mods.  They also get an armor, armor variant, weapon skin, and a set of visors.

The armor mods provide the following abilities.

- Engineers get to see weapon drops early
- Operators reduce the effects of plasma pistols on vehicles they drive, and reduce the chances of getting hijacked.
- Pathfinders reduce weapon heat-up on turrets and move faster when carrying them.
- Pioneers get experience bonuses.
- Rouges have increased weapon stability when under fire.
- Stalkers get the person who killed them last lit up on their HUD
- Trackers get better ordnance drop options.
- Wetwork allows for reduced stealth detection from motion sensors and Promethean vision, and they get faster assassination animations.

[From the wiki.](http://www.halopedia.org/Specializations)

Comment: Ah, seems the Wiki gets updated quicker than I tend to give it credit for. It says `the player must choose one to advance through before they can select another` so after you get one to rank 10 you can unlock another? And another until you have them all and all abilities?

Comment: Yeah, I believe that you can complete all of the specializations, if you have the time to reach SR 130.